# Atom packages not working even when enabled

Tags: html, package, atom-editor

I installed all Atom packages mentioned on this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQNuhDC5pFXEVVNGasvddKuDHEXnqR033lsSD5tLA9NiEdHrsYM4MXVEXja2RnBgsCxK6XEo6YkMOFI/pub).

```
atom-beautify
atom-ternjs
autoclose-html
emmet
csslint
pigments
language-ejs
atom-html-preview
Sublime-Style-Column-Selection
linter-eslint
```

I made an file index.html. But whenever I type something it doesn't show any suggestions. Also when I type html and hit tab or enter it doesn't show boilerplate code.

I tried disabling and then enabling, restarting Atom as well as Laptop but it didn't worked. I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Does the completion popup show up when you press `Ctrl`+`Space`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create that new file with extension .html  U must have not used the .html  extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).